# How to check how many times a substring occurs within a string?

Tags: c++

I am writing a function that searches for a substring in a given string and returns how many times the substring occurs in the string.  For example, if the functions parameters were ("hellohello", "hel") the function would return 2.  I apologize if the answer is obvious, I am relatively new to c++.

The if loop that i've created hasn't been working, and I'm not sure why.  My function returns 0 when I call it in the main() function with its parameters set to ("hellohello", "hel").

```cpp
int countMatches(string input, string substring)
{
    if(input == "" || substring == "")
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int matches;

        int substringLength = substring.length() - 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) 
        {
            if(input.substr(i, substringLength) == substring)
            {
                matches++;
                return matches;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main(){

    //test 1 
    //expected output 2
    cout << countMatches("hellohello", "hel") << endl;

}
```

Comment: On the first match, your function exits due to that hard `return matches;`. More importantly, however, this is far more broken than that. If either input string is zero-length, the result is `-1`. ok. But... if there is at least one match the result is undefined since `matches` is never initialized, and in the case of no match on valid arguments the results are undefined since you provide no return value whatsoever in that case. Turn up your warnings, you should be being warned about at least one code path that specifies no return value in this function.

Comment: Ok, so I changed int matches; to int matches = 0;  I also put return matches outside of the for loop but still within the else statement.  I am still getting 0 for some reason.  When I run it with the debugger on, the for loop iterates properly, but it never recognizes that "hellohello" contains "hel", so matches remains at 0.  This makes me think that the problem is within the for loop argument.

Comment: @FIFO1175 You should post your updated code here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem specification is slightly ambiguous. Can the substrings overlap? For example, if you're looking for the number of times `AA` occurs in `AAAA`, do you consider the correct answer to be 2 or 3?

Either way, we can use `std::string::find` to find the substrings. `find` takes a parameter to specify where it should start looking for a match. So, if we want to allow overlapping sub-strings, we search from the beginning, then each time we find a sub-string we re-start the search from one position after the beginning of the match we found.

If we only want to allow non-overlapping sub-strings, we start the same (search from the beginning) but when we find a substring we restart the search from just past the end of the substring we just find.

So, here's a version that'll count overlapping substrings:

```
size_t count_substrings(std::string const &needle, std::string const &haystack) {
    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t pos =0; (pos=haystack.find(needle, pos)) != std::string::npos; ++pos, ++count)
        ;

   return count;
}
```

The modification necessary to count non-overlapping substrings is left as an exercise for the reader (but it honestly is pretty simple).

Comment: I saw the find function mentioned in other posts, however, I'm not supposed to use things that my professor hasn't covered in class yet.  The substrings can overlap.  I really appreciate the helpful answer, and I would totally use it if I could, but the find function is out of my allowed realm of c++ usage.  I realize I should've specified this in my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int SIZE = 100, lengthOfMainString = 0, lengthOfSubString = 0, counter = 0;

char mainString[SIZE], subString[SIZE];

cout << "enter main string: ";
cin.getline(mainString, SIZE);

cout << "enter sub string: ";
cin.getline(subString, SIZE);

while (mainString[lengthOfMainString] != '\0')
{
    lengthOfMainString++;
}

while (subString[lengthOfSubString] != '\0')
{
    lengthOfSubString++;
}

cout << "Main String length: " << lengthOfMainString << endl;
cout << "Sub String length: " << lengthOfSubString << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfMainString; i++)
{
    int ch = 0;

    while (ch < lengthOfSubString)
    {
        if (mainString[i + ch] != subString[ch])
        {
            break;
        }
        ch++;
    }
    if (ch == lengthOfSubString)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}

cout << "The substring " << subString << " appeared " << counter << " times." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug in your program is on this line:

```
        int substringLength = substring.length() - 1;
```

This sets `substringLength` to one less than the length of `substring`.  Consequently, the result of `substr()` is always short by one character, and is hence never equal to `substring`.

You want instead:

```
        int substringLength = substring.length();
```

With that change, plus initializing `matches` to 0 and returning it at the end of the `else` block, the program prints "2".  (You should also `return 0;` at the end of `main()`.)